# Python3: How do I get a warning that server memory is running out?

Tags: exception, memory-management, python-3.x

I'm writing a program that manages data entered by users. I plan to open a test version to the public and have no idea how many users there may be.

I want my program to test when memory is getting low so that I know when to buy more server space and so that I can automatically restrict data entry when necessary. What's a good way to detect memory shortage? Allocate garbage space temporarily to get the exception? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

This may be best accomplished outside of your application using a performance monitoring tool. Windows Server can be configured to do this for you; see [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/404479/how-can-i-monitor-memory-usage-for-a-windows-based-jvm-and-trigger-an-alert-if-i) question. There are other tools out there that help you monitor your servers, and I advise you to use an existing system unless you absolutely have to do this with Python.

If you must absolutely do this using Python, then have a look at the [psutil](https://code.google.com/p/psutil/) library:

> psutil (python system and process utilities) is a cross-platform
>   library for retrieving     information on running processes and system
>   utilization (CPU, memory, disks, network) in Python. It is useful
>   mainly for system monitoring, profiling and limiting process resources
>   and management of running processes. It implements many
>   functionalities offered by command line tools such as: ps, top, lsof,
>   netstat, ifconfig, who, df, kill, free, nice, ionice, iostat, iotop,
>   uptime, pidof, tty, taskset, pmap. It currently supports Linux,
>   Windows, OSX, FreeBSD and Sun Solaris, both 32-bit and 64-bit
>   architectures, with Python versions from 2.4 to 3.4. Pypi is also
>   known to work.

You may combine this with the [email](http://docs.python.org/2/library/email.html#module-email) package to send the alerts.

Comment: I'm not using Windows Server, and probably switch to AWS, which will surely have ways to do it.

Comment: @user3354588 no worries :). My point was that you should investigate these tools and see if they cater to your needs.